# ImportError: cannot import name 'SegmentationMapsOnImage' from 'imgaug.augmentables.segmaps'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, importerror

When i import it, i get an error about that.

```
from imgaug.augmentables.segmaps import SegmentationMapsOnImage
```

Error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SegmentationMapsOnImage' from
> 'imgaug.augmentables.segmaps'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/imgaug/augmentables/segmaps.py)

[Here is the documentation link](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/imgaug/augmentables/segmaps.html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of the package are you using?

Comment: python 3.7 , imgaug 1.15.0

Comment: 1.15.0?  Are you sure?  The doc page says the latest is 0.4.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i still get the same error. I changed version after you had said. what could it be caused by?

Comment: You still haven't said what version you are using.

Comment: 2.9.0 Sir. I can't write quickly because I'm using Colab. :)

Comment: Again, I don't see how that's possible, because the doc page says the latest version is 0.4.

Comment: I've written wrong. 0.2.9

Comment: Install the latest version of the package.  That class was probably added in a newer version than you have.

Comment: Thanks sir! It's resolved.